# How to Specify Superclass when Creating New Class

Tags: android-studio

I have not been able to figure out how to specify a superclass when creating a new class in Android Studio. I know I can manually accomplish this using the `extends` keyword but I was wondering if there was a way to specify superclass while creating the subclass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest method I have found to achieve something similar is File and Code Templates. Press **Ctrl+Alt+S** and go to **File and Code Templates** in the IDE Settings. Now you can create your own template by clicking on the green plus sign.

Here's an example of one that I created based on the Class Template:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} extends ${SUPERCLASS} {
}
```

The only difference between this and the default Class template is that I've added `extends ${SUPERCLASS}`. ${SUPERCLASS} is a custom variable which will be prompted to be used when using this template.

Comment: I am sorry I have to ask a stupid question, but how to use the template to create a new class?